# EMV Question : What kind of data do Issuer need to verify my card beside AC information?

Tags: emv

May I know that after the generate a AC , what kind of information i need to pass to issue for verification ?  Do i need to send my AC with PAN , PAN SN , CID and ATC to issuer for card identification ?

Thank you
David

Answer (score 1):

Simple rule - data used during creation should be available during verification. The data elements used for creating GEN AC1 you can find from CDOL1. (another is to get it from Cryptogram version number, check based on context) These data you should make sure is passed to issuer. Card sequence number is not a part of CDOL1, but this has to be made available to the issuer( a common mistake).

Comment: Apart from data from CDOL1 data and CSN (as you wrote), AIP is also necessary.